# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x_direction' referenced before assignment, Back and Forth movement in Pygame 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Im running Python 3.8.2 and Pygame 2.0.0.dev6 in Pycharm.

I read a few of the other threads on similar issues but couldn't figure out why I'm getting this error in this instance. The purpose of this post is two-fold: 1 is that I would like to understand this error (I am very new to programming), and 2 is that I would like to know if there is a better method to accomplish what I am trying to do.

I am trying to make enemies that sway back and forth in the x-direction, their change being triggered either by a certain amount of time passing or (haven't added this yet) a certain number of collisions with other enemies.

The error seems to be triggered by the second if statement in the `movement` method here:

```
class EnemyShip(ShipGeneral):
    MOVEMENT_TIME = 180
    SHIP_TYPE_DIC = {
        'pawn': Images().pawn_ship_img,
        'boss': Images().boss_ship_img
    }

    def __init__(self, x, y, enemy_type=None):
        super().__init__(x, y, enemy_type)
        self.ship_img = self.SHIP_TYPE_DIC[enemy_type]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
        self.health = 100
        self.movement_time_counter = 0  # Defaut set to zero

    def movement_timer(self):
        if self.movement_time_counter >= self.MOVEMENT_TIME:
            self.movement_time_counter = 0
        elif self.movement_time_counter > 0:
            self.movement_time_counter +=1

    def movement(self):  # TODO fix enemy movement to prevent overlapping and allow for advances
        y_vel = 10
        x_vel = 2
        boundaries = Settings()
        if self.y <= 100:
            self.y += y_vel
        if self.movement_time_counter == 0:  # should be true and run first in the while loop
            x_direction = random.choice(['R', 'L'])
            self.movement_time_counter += 1
        if x_direction == 'R' and self.x + self.ship_img.get_width() + x_vel < boundaries.screen_width:
                self.x += x_vel
        if x_direction == 'L' and self.x > 0:
                self.x -= x_vel
```

I call the class and the functions in the game's main while loop here:

```
enemies = []
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    gf.check_events()  # checks for user quit event
    if len(enemies) == 0:  # updates level and spawns new enemies after each wave
        level += 1
        fleet_size += 5
        for enemy in range(fleet_size):
            enemy = EnemyShip(
                random.randrange(20, 800 - 20),
                random.randrange(-1000, -100, 10),
                enemy_type=random.choice(['pawn', 'pawn', 'pawn', 'pawn', 'boss'])
            )
            enemies.append(enemy)

    for enemy in enemies: # enables each enemy to move
        enemy.movement()
        enemy.move_missile(7, playership)
        enemy.movement_timer()
        if enemy.health <=0:
            enemies.remove(enemy)
```

If I run this I get the following error:

> ```
>    File >"/Users/aaronbastian/Documents/PythonCode/Part_II_Projects/alien_invasion/ships.py", line 114, in movement
>    if x_direction == 'R' and self.x + self.ship_img.get_width() + x_vel < boundaries.screen_width:
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x_direction' referenced before assignment
> ```

I don't understand the error because I thought `self.movement_time_counter == 0` should evaluate to True and thus assign `x_direction` before the following if statements were run.

If someone could explain to me my error, I would greatly appreciate it! Also, I apologize if this is a redundant post, I just couldn't understand the other similar threads.

Comment: first use `print(self.movement_time_counter)` to see if it gives `0` - if not then you should set ie `x_direction = None` at the beginning of `movement` to create this variable with default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised during compilation because you have not initialized the variable anywhere. Just initialize the variable with some default value in the ____init____().
Example:

```
self.x_direction = None
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 i think there is no problem in adding self, even your solution demands that!

Comment: @Rabbid76 well yes I did have to change x_direction everywhere, but I don't see any issue doing that.  I did that and It worked immediately. when I initialized it, I set x_direction = 'R', which doesn't really matter what its set to because it will be overwritten in the aforementioned if statement.